# pkill isn't fully killing process?

Tags: bash, cron, flock, pkill

I'm doing some testing with `flock` and `pkill` for a `test.sh` script that I'm calling from `cron` and I ran into something I don't understand.

The `test.sh` is scheduled as a `* * * * *` job in cron. Its a very simple script that for testing purposes writes a timestamp to file and then sleeps for 5 minutes. This is to confirm `flock` is working well and preventing multiple processes for the same script.

This part is working well as I only see one timestamp showing up per 5 minutes despite the `test.sh` being scheduled to run every minute.

Now as a extra safety measure I want to kill the `test.sh` (because the script I actually want to use sometimes appears to hang syncing some files to S3 using AWS CLI)

So I figured `pkill` would be the easiest as it doesn't require modifying anything to my existing script.

If I run `pkill -9 -f test.sh` it says the processes is killed. Running `ps aux | grep test.sh` I indeed don't see any `test.sh` processes anymore.

However as `cron` is supposed to `test.sh` every minute, I expect that after killing the process, it would start again after less than a minute.

However it appears that the script doesn't actually restart until the sleep period is over.

So the script initially runs at e.g. `12:00`, sleep will last until `12:05`. If I kill the script on `12:02` I expect it to run again at `12:03` but it's not actually running again until `12:05` which is inline with the sleep period.

Why is this happening? Also, if `pkill` is not recommended, is there any other way to kill my processes after a certain amount of time? Preferably without having to edit the original script.

Comment: Please show your .sh file.

Comment: My .sh is dead simple.

echo "this is a test" >> test.txt
sleep 1800

Sorry for the poor formatting, can't figure out for the life of me how to get stack to not suck with their impossible formatting.

Answer (score 1):

See the following example:

```
 1  exec 9> /tmp/flock.tmp
 2  if ! flock -n 9; then
 3      echo "locked by others!"
 4      exit 1
 5  fi
 6
 7  sleep 300
```

Line 1 opens FD 9 on the lockfile. Line 2's `flock` sets a lock on the FD. Line 7's `sleep` inherits the FD and keeps it being locked. When you `pkill` the `.sh` script it'll not kill `sleep` so the FD is still locked until `sleep` finishes. So, to clean up, you need to kill all running processes after `flock`.

---

[`flock(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) uses [`flock(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) and according to `flock(2)`:

> Locks  created  by `flock()` are associated with an open file description (see `open(2)`).  This means that duplicate file descriptors (created by, for example, `fork(2)` or `dup(2)`) refer to the same lock, and this lock may be modified or released using any of these file descriptors.  Furthermore, **the lock is released either by an explicit `LOCK_UN` operation on any of these  duplicate  file  descriptors,  or  when  all  such  file descriptors have been closed**.